# mavros: How to use setpoint_raw/local and set the FRAME_BODY_OFFSET_NED flag

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, mavros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using the mavros package but I'm not sure on how to use a certain message type. I want to use this: `setpoint_raw/local (mavros_msgs/PositionTarget)` message type and want to set the `FRAME_BODY_OFFSET_NED` flag, but I'm not sure on how to do it. Can someone explain this to me?

I was also planning to use the velocity part of the message, but thats quite simple. I will do it as folow:

```
vel_msg.velocity.x = 0.1;
vel_msg.velocity.y = 0.0;
vel_msg.velocity.z = 0.0;
```

Of cours I will first declare the publisher and the message.

[Message type](http://docs.ros.org/api/mavros_msgs/html/msg/PositionTarget.html)

[Mavros](http://wiki.ros.org/mavros#mavros.2BAC8-Plugins.setpoint_position)

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278109/mavros:-how-to-use-setpoint_raw/local-and-set-the-frame_body_offset_ned-flag/) by [MaximeRector](https://answers.ros.org/users/29590/maximerector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`FRAME_BODY_OFFSET_NED` is a flag that's defined in the message. By convention, flags should have the same prefix as the message field that they relate to. In this case the `FRAME_*` flags are directly below the `coordinate_frame` field, so they appear to be related. A quick Google search reveals a code snippet that confirms this hypothesis:

```
moveMsg.coordinate_frame = mavros_msgs::PositionTarget::FRAME_BODY_OFFSET_NED;
```

Happy roboting!

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0